# Compactness and directed systems of subspaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness, limits-colimits

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $K$ be a subspace of $X$. It is easy to verify the claim below:

> Let $\{ U_j : j \in J \}$ be a directed system of open subspaces of $X$ with the following property:
>
> - We have $\bigcup_{j \in J} U_j = X$.
>
> If $K$ is a compact subspace of $X$, then there is some $j \in J$ such that $K \subseteq U_j$.

Less well known is this fact:

> Let $\{ F_\alpha : \alpha < \lambda \}$ be an increasing sequence of closed subspaces of $X$ with the following properties:
>
> - If $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal $< \lambda$, then $F_\gamma = \bigcup_{\alpha < \gamma} F_\alpha$ and has the colimit topology.
> - $X = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} F_\alpha = X$ and has the colimit topology.
> - If $x \in X \setminus F_\alpha$, then $\overline{\{ x \}} \subseteq X \setminus F_\alpha$.
>
> If $K$ is a compact closed subspace of $X$, then there is some $\alpha < \lambda$ such that $K \subseteq F_\alpha$.

**Question.** Is there a result generalising both of the above statements?

Comment: Both covers are similar in the sense that the last condition of the second formulation holds for both (they are inductive covers). The first condition for closed covers trivially holds for open covers (so these covers are "point-closure evading"). This might point to a generalisation: consider all directed, inductive covers with "point-closure evading" members.

Comment: Wait, I don't believe that second fact.  Let $X$ be any sequential Hausdorff space and let the $F_j$ be all the closed countable subspaces of $X$.  Then your hypotheses are satisfied, but $X$ can certainly have uncountable compact subspaces.

Comment: Huh, right. So I need more hypotheses on the system of closed subsets...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a common generalization:

> Let $\lambda>0$ be an ordinal and let $\{ F_\alpha : \alpha < \lambda \}$ be an increasing sequence of subspaces of $X$ with the following properties:
>
> - If $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal $< \lambda$, then $F_\gamma = \bigcup_{\alpha < \gamma} F_\alpha$ and has the colimit topology.
> - $X = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} F_\alpha = X$ and has the colimit topology.
> - If $x \in X \setminus F_\alpha$, then $\overline{\{ x \}} \subseteq X \setminus F_\alpha$.
>
> If $K$ is a compact subspace of $X$, then there is some $\alpha < \lambda$ such that $K \subseteq F_\alpha$.

This obviously contains your second result (with the minor correction that $\lambda$ can't be $0$) as a special case: we have just removed the requirement that $K$ and the $F_\alpha$ are closed.  Let's see how it contains your first result as a special case.  If $\{U_j:j\in J\}$ is a directed family of open sets with $X=\bigcup U_j$, pick a well-ordering on $J$ and write $V_j=\bigcup_{i<j} U_j$.  Since the $U_j$ are open, the sets $V_j$ automatically satisfy the three conditions above (any space is the colimit of any open cover).  If $K\subseteq X$ is compact, we conclude that $K\subseteq V_j$ for some $j$; choose the least such $j$.  Then $j$ must be either a successor or $0$ (otherwise we could repeat the argument with $\lambda=j$ to find a smaller one); if $j\neq 0$, let $K'=K\setminus U_{j-1}$.  Then $K'\subseteq V_{j-1}$ and $K'$ is compact.  Repeating the argument with $K'$ in place of $K$, we get a minimal $j'<j$ such that $K'\subseteq V_{j'}$.  Continuing by induction, we get a descending sequence $j>j'>j''>\dots$ which must terminate since $J$ is well-ordered.  When it terminates, we find that $K$ is covered by the finitely many sets $U_{j-1},U_{j'-1},U_{j''-1},\dots$.  Since the $U_j$ are directed, this means there is a single $j^*$ such that $K\subseteq U_{j^*}$.

Let us now prove the generalization.  Suppose $X$ is a space with subspaces $F_\alpha$ as above. Suppose $K\subseteq X$ is compact and is not contained in any $F_\alpha$. Passing to a closed unbounded subsequence of the $F_\alpha$, we may choose a point $x_\alpha\in K\cap F_{\alpha+1}\setminus F_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$.  For each $\beta<\lambda$, let $C_\beta=\{x_\alpha:\beta\leq\alpha\}$ and let $D_{\beta\alpha}$ denote the closure of $C_\beta\cap F_\alpha$ in $F_\alpha$.

Let us now prove by induction on $\alpha$ that $D_{\beta\alpha}\cap F_\gamma=D_{\beta\gamma}$ for all $\gamma<\alpha$.  For $\alpha$ limit, note that the induction hypothesis implies that $\bigcup_{\gamma<\alpha} D_{\beta\gamma}$ is closed in $F_\gamma$ for each $\gamma<\alpha$ (since its intersection with $F_\gamma$ is just $D_{\beta\gamma}$) and thus $\bigcup_{\gamma<\alpha} D_{\beta\gamma}$ is closed in $F_\alpha$.  It follows that $\bigcup_{\gamma<\alpha} D_{\beta\gamma}=D_{\beta\alpha}$ and thus that $D_{\beta\alpha}\cap F_\gamma=D_{\beta\gamma}$ for all $\gamma<\alpha$.

Now suppose $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal.  Let $A=\{x_\gamma:\beta\leq\gamma<\alpha-1\}$ and $B=\{x_{\alpha-1}\}$ and note that $C_\beta\cap F_\alpha=A\cup B$.  Thus $D_{\beta\alpha}=(\overline{A}\cap F_{\alpha})\cup (\overline{B}\cap F_{\alpha})$ and so $D_{\beta\alpha}\cap F_{\alpha-1}=(\overline{A}\cap F_{\alpha-1})\cup (\overline{B}\cap F_{\alpha-1})$.  Moreover, since $A\subseteq F_{\alpha-1}$, $\overline{A}\cap F_{\alpha-1}$ is just the closure of $A$ in $F_{\alpha-1}$, which is $D_{\beta(\alpha-1)}$.  Also, $\overline{B}\cap F_{\alpha-1}=\emptyset$ since $x_{\alpha-1}\not\in F_{\alpha-1}$.  Thus $D_{\beta\alpha}\cap F_{\alpha-1}=D_{\beta(\alpha-1)}$ and the desired conclusion for arbitrary $\gamma<\alpha$ follows from the induction hypothesis.

Now let $D_\beta=\overline{C_\beta}$.  By the same argument as in the limit step above, $D_\beta=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda} D_{\beta\alpha}$, and so $D_\beta\cap F_\alpha=D_{\beta\alpha}$ for all $\alpha<\lambda$.  In particular, $D_\beta\cap F_\beta=D_{\beta\beta}=\emptyset$ since $C_\beta\cap F_\beta=\emptyset$.

Thus $\bigcap_{\beta<\lambda} D_\beta$ does not intersect any $F_\beta$ and so is empty.  Since the $D_\beta$ are closed and descending and $K$ is compact, there must be a single $\beta$ such that $K\cap D_\beta=\emptyset$ (this is the step where we use $\lambda>0$, since we need to know that $\lambda$ is directed).  But by construction, $x_\beta\in K\cap D_\beta$.  This is a contradiction.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know about nets, so I can't follow your proof. I wonder if there might be a more elementary proof, along the lines of Proposition 2.4.2 in [Hovey, _Model categories_]?

Comment: You can pretend you're working in a first-countable space and substitute "sequence" everywhere I say "net" and you won't really be missing anything important about the argument.  I don't immediately see a simple way to rephrase the proof; you need to somehow show that $\overline{C_\beta}\cap F_\beta=\emptyset$, and since all you know about the topology is that it is the colimit topology, it seems like you have to somehow explicitly describe a set containing $C_\beta$ and disjoint from $F_\beta$ and then prove that it is closed (like I do with my $D_\beta$).

Comment: In particular, Hovey's argument seems to make heavy use of the assumption that the $F_\alpha$ are closed, which allows the argument to be vastly simpler (you can take just a countable sequence of points $x_{\alpha_n}$ instead of going all the way out the $\lambda$, which then means that the corresponding set $C_\beta$ is actually already closed in $F_\mu$ for $\mu=\sup \alpha_n$ and you don't have to give a complicated description of its closure to prove the closure is disjoint from $F_\beta$).

Comment: To put it another way, I would say my argument _is_ along the lines of Hovey's, just with the necessary modifications to make it work with the weaker hypotheses here.  Indeed, I came up with it by imitating that argument and then seeing which parts broke down and how they needed to be modified to still work in this generality.

Comment: Well, three and half years later I've taken another look at it and found a nice way to write the argument in simpler language.  It's still considerably more complicated than Hovey's argument when the $F_\alpha$ are closed.